# How to find the secret case "Friendly Faces" in Another Case Solved?

Tags: another-case-solved

I have completed the main story line, found and completed all the other secret cases, and still this case eludes me. Do I need to buy something specific to unlock it, or something?

Answer (score 1):

You have to click on the plus sign next to the candies at the top and click Like on Facebook.